# widehat shifted to the right whereas having to be centered

Tags: math-mode, accents

I have the following expression :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\widehat{o_{\ell }} = 
\frac{1}{2l+1} \sum_m\dfrac{\widehat{|a_{\ell m,\rm sp}|^2}}{|a_{\ell m,\rm ph}|^2}
\]
\end{document}
```

that renders :

[image]

(original:
[image: widehat shifted to the right]
)

As you can see, the second \widehat is shifted to the right and I don't know how to center it.

Comment: note `\rm` has not been defined by default in latex for 30 years.

Comment: The positioning of the accent depends on the font about which you gave no information, I fixed your question to include an example (using default fonts) which also shows the issue, although you were clearly using different fonts.

Comment: the widehat is centered on |...|^2 but can not stretch that wide, did you intend to center in on |...| ?

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to see what is happening with a font that has wider `^` I use stix2 here, although that still does not have a hat wide enough for your original term.

the accent is centered, but just looks offset as it is covering the superscript 2. It looks more centred (but means a different mathematical operation) if you just apply it to the base.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
widhat of (foo squared)
\[
\widehat{o_{\ell }} = 
\frac{1}{2l+1} \sum_m\dfrac{\widehat{|a_{\ell m,\mathrm {sp}}|^2}}{|a_{\ell m,\mathrm{ph}}|^2}
\]
square of(widehat of foo)
\[
\widehat{o_{\ell }} = 
\frac{1}{2l+1} \sum_m\dfrac{\widehat{|a_{\ell m,\mathrm {sp}}|}^2}{|a_{\ell m,\mathrm{ph}}|^2}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The superscript 2 might look better (less up in the blue) if you put the hat only on what is inside the absolute value (I would guess that is also intended).

Comment: @DavidCarliste . Thanks, is it possible to get the upper squared symbol less up in your solution ?

Comment: @guizmo133 what meaning do you intend (the reader will find it to distinguish these two in any case unless you find a wider hat)  in the second one here the 2 is superscripting the expression with the hat so is positioned by the height of the central point of the ^, you could of course fake things eg `\widehat{...}`{}^2` so the 2 was on a null base but that makes it even harder for a reader to see the structure.